# Automatically update ip-address in hosts file?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, windows-7, vmware-player, hosts-file

My development environment is Ubuntu guest OS inside VMWare Player with Windows 7 as the host OS.  I edit the hosts file in windows to point http://dev.mydomain.com to the ip-address of my VM so that I can test browsers in windows.  I love this setup, but have to update my hosts file quite often to take advantage of it.  Is there a way to either prevent the ip-address from changing so frequently, or to automatically update the hosts file when it changes?

Comment: Is your Virtual networking setup NAT or bridged? Any reason why you can't just set a static IP in Ubuntu?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking how to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be simpler to set your virtual machines networking to Bridged and set a static IP up in Ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome, can you point me in the right direction on how to do that?  I tried changing VMWare player to bridged, after which my hosts don't seem to work anymore

Comment: Nevermind, I probably just didn't wait long enough for the settings to kick in.  Thanks!